# Why does this index provide only a constant time improvement to a GROUP BY query?

Tags: mysql, go, mysql-5.6

I'm running MySQL 5.6 and building applications in Go. I've had a stubborn query that will not optimize, so I am trying to break it down to its barest component. The fundamental problem is that **indices on GROUP BY columns give a constant improvement in runtime, not a logarithmic performance as I would have expected**.

Here is an example with benchmarks. Given this `data.go`:

```
package data

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

type GroupCount struct {
    Cohort string
    Cnt    uint
}

func GroupByQuery(db *sql.DB) ([]GroupCount, error) {

    var counts []GroupCount

    res, err := db.Query(`
        SELECT cohort, COUNT(cohort) AS cnt
        FROM test_table
        GROUP BY cohort
    `)
    defer res.Close()

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return []GroupCount{}, err
    }

    for res.Next() {
        var gc GroupCount
        err := res.Scan(&gc.Cohort, &gc.Cnt)
        if err != nil {
            return []GroupCount{}, err
        }

        counts = append(counts, gc)
    }

    return counts, nil

}
```

and `data_test.go`:

```
package data

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "testing"
    "time"
)

func BenchmarkGroupByQuery(b *testing.B) {

    // local db connection
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "dbuser:dbpass@tcp(localhost:3306)/testdb")
    defer db.Close()

    // declare db table
    db.Exec("DROP TABLE test_table")

    _, err = db.Exec("CREATE TABLE test_table (id INT, cohort VARCHAR(255))")
    if err != nil {
        b.Fatal(err)
    }
    // comment in or out to test index
    // _, err = db.Exec("CREATE INDEX idx_cohort ON test_table (cohort)")
    // if err != nil {
    //  b.Fatal(err)
    // }

    // insert some data into the table
    n := 100000
    stmt := "INSERT INTO test_table VALUES (%d, %s)"

    rand.Seed(time.Now().UnixNano())

    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        j := rand.Intn(5)
        insertStmt := fmt.Sprintf(stmt, i, fmt.Sprintf("\"group%d\"", j))

        _, err := db.Exec(insertStmt)
        if err != nil {
            b.Error(err)
        }
    }

    b.ResetTimer()

    // access and print results
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        GroupByQuery(db)
    }
}
```

To replicate, you will need to setup the appropriate database in MySQL with user access. Running the given benchmark ( `go test . --bench BenchmarkGroupByQuery`) with a variable `n`, I get the following results:

```
unindexed
i = 100    :   0.5 ms/op
i = 1000   :   2.3 ms/op
i = 10000  :  20.1 ms/op
i = 100000 : 215.6 ms/op
indexed
i = 100    :  0.2 ms/op
i = 1000   :  0.7 ms/op
i = 10000  :  6.0 ms/op
i = 100000 : 59.6 ms/op
```

I can verify that the query with and without the index gives a different execution plan indicating use or not-use of the index, given a large data set divided between 5 groups.

Without index

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT cohort, COUNT(cohort) AS cnt FROM test_table GROUP BY cohort;
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_table | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 100256 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+---------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

With index

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT cohort, COUNT(cohort) AS cnt FROM test_table GROUP BY cohort;
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test_table | index | idx_cohort    | idx_cohort | 768     | NULL | 100256 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+------------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Finally, here is the result of the query itself (which is somewhat random, given the setup in the benchmark)

```
mysql> SELECT cohort, COUNT(cohort) AS cnt FROM test_table GROUP BY cohort;
+--------+-------+
| cohort | cnt   |
+--------+-------+
| group0 | 19928 |
| group1 | 19791 |
| group2 | 19916 |
| group3 | 20282 |
| group4 | 20083 |
+--------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.07 sec)
```

These results are very surprising to me. Essentially, adding an index on the column by which we group gives a roughly constant runtime improvement factor of ~0.3. I don't understand why it would not either give a logarithmic runtime improvement, or no improvement at all.

Comment: I would have expected no improvement at all, or just very marginal improvement.  It is difficult to optimize `COUNT`, since your query has no `WHERE` or `HAVING` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT cohort, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM test_table
    GROUP BY cohort
```

Runs in "linear" time.  That is O(N).  Your timings show (except for tiny tables) that sorting 10x rows take 10x as long.

The 100-row test and 1000-row test do not differ by a full 10x because of the overhead of parsing the query, opening the table, and other "overhead".  That overhead is amortized for larger tables.

The difference between without and with index is simple.  That query will be performed one of two ways:

- No useful index: A table scan (cf ALL).  The entire table will be read.
- `INDEX(cohort)`: An index scan (cf "Using index").  The entire index will be read.

The table and the index are each stored in their own BTrees.

- The full table's BTree has all the columns.
- The index's BTree has only `cohort` and the columns of the `PRIMARY KEY`.

The index's BTree is smaller, so the full scan takes less time.

There are multiple ways that the optimizer might perform such a count.

Plan A: (non-indexed) Build a hash table in RAM and count the cohorts as they are encountered.
Plan B: (indexed) Walk through the index counting occurrences of one value at a time.
Plan C: (non-indexed, but decided against Plan A) Collect all the values into a temp table, sort that table, *then* do Plan B.

I do not know of a way to force Plan C to be used.  Since sort is O(N*LogN), is that where you are getting "logarithmic"?